# VS Code does not show Salesforce object or class symbols when typing. Code completion does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex

I have the Salesforce extension pack installed. I have VSCode set up with my org. I have pulled down my classes and pages that I need to develop. When I go to actually develop - I make an instance of my object - I go to fill the properties of that object but no properties appear.

example:

```
Account account = new Account();

// normally you have this scenario:
account.(shows property list here like name, balance, etc.) 

// what i get:
account.(nothing shows here, not even an empty list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by installing java 8 jdk and referencing the right java path in the settings.json file.